# iOS : Adaptative view size programmatically depending on iphone model

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, layout, autolayout

I'm creating views programmatically and they are stacked on each other like a deck. I'd like them to have a specific size regarding the size of the screen.

How can I adapt each view's frame to so that they are all laid out evenly and accommodate the main screen size (for ex. iPhone 4) or any other iPhone screen size?

For now, I have this piece of code:

```
var frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 435)
switch [iphone model] {
  case [iphone4]:
    frame.size.height = frame.size.height * [sizeFactor]
    frame.size.width = frame.size.width * [sizeFactor]
  case [iphone5]:
    [...]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Well you answered yourself already correctly in principle.. What specifically is the problem?

Comment: I answered myself ? I don't think i've figure out how to determine the sizeFactor regarding the iphone model and how to have the reference value to switch on for the iphone model

Comment: Ok then the question should ask "how to detect ios device model programatically?". Because obviously you understand switch and you know how to assign a new frame. Right?

Comment: No, the question is what i asked, or if you prefer : "How to make the size of a view frame vary regarding the screen size of the device". In IB you have auto-layout constraints, but how to do that when you create views programmatically when you have to set a specific size in pixel ? I used the switch as an example, but i suppose there should be something for that, like auto-layout in IB, not to do that by if/switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement your layout mechanism manually.

if the parent view uses

**AUTOLAYOUT**

1) generate your views

2) generate constraints (for each view you will need - width, height, margins..or some more advanced "equality of sizes" constraint) that will pick up the actual constant property values from helper methods.

3) helper methods will calculate the particular height, width or any other constant based on the ratio of screen and number of views visible.

4) Apply constraints to views

---

**SPRINGS & STRUTS** (old way to layout views)

1) generate your views

2) calculate frames for them ...for frame member values use dynamically calculated values from helper methods

3) implement the helper methods which will use the screen size ..same as autolayout 3)

4) set correct autoresizing masks to all views.

Comment: Ok, I'm using autolayout in IB. So when you say generating constraints, i have to use some NSLayoutConstraint to apply to my main view, right ?

Comment: No. In 4) I am saying apply to views. plural :)...you want to constraint your views..you don't want to play with viewcontroller's root view which is full screen..right? So you need to apply those constraints to the generated views then..

Comment: Ok. I was hoping there was something more easier provided by apple regarding the different screens size to manage. I will try that then, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the window size at runtime:

```
CGRect windowRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Comment: Sure, i know how to get the window size, and even the iphone model with UIDevice, but i'd like to have my frame adapting automatically regarding his original size, maybe by a factor provided by the framework or something else provided by apple for this kind of need, but i can't find something like that.

Comment: I don't get your point ... every iphone model gives you the window size so you can layout your subviews depending on that. Or even better ... use auto layout for layouting your views.